# Object intersection in 2d

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, vision

image(1)
[image: img(1)]

image(2)
[image: img(2) from top view]

I having 2 images image(1) and image(2)

image(1): I placed camera on some fixed place and captured this image. I having box coordinates(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) which is shown by red bounding box. Also I having some region of interest(ROI) which is shown by blue box.

image(2): From top I am captured this image. Here also I just drawn box coordinates(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) which is shown by red bounding box. Also drawn region of interest(ROI) which is shown by blue box.

in image(1) we can see some intersection between the red box and blue box. But this intersection not the real one. because when we see the image from top view we can see there is no intersection between them as I showed in image(2).

So for image(1) I having red rectangle coordinates(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax). This red rectangle contains the object. In that red rectangle I don't having the information about the object position/direction and visible corner points of object. (Because from object detector I only getting this red rectangle). Also, I have blue box(ROI) coordinates. Is there any way with the help of camera calibration(or any other computer vision method) to find this 2 boxes (Red rectangle and blue ROI) are not really intersecting in image(1)?

Comment: sure it is possible. If you know the size and orientation of the object you can find the 3D ground point position of the objects. But for a moving camera without scene markes and for arbitrary objects you likely will not be able to determine those parameters dynamically in the precidion needed for the case in your sample image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The camera is fixed. And with camera calibration I will get all the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. The blue box and red box pixel coordinates already with me as I shown in image(1). So with the help of this how to find whether objects(image(1)) intersecting or not? Can you give any direction in this way...

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the attached image. You might have to zoom in. Remind that there is still lens distortion and I just used my hands to draw the lines, so not really accurate but hopefully enough to get the idea.

[image]

After calibrating the scene, you will know the ground plane in which the blue rectangle is defined and the object is lying on that ground plane. I just used the paper squares and directions, but the coordinate axes can be arbitrary.

You can compute the vanishing point of the object bounding box directions, which is the dark green lines intersection and the orange lines intersection (z direction vanishing point) and the cyan line intersection (y direction vanishing point). Orange and dark green lines are parallel in reality.

Now from the top-left corner point of the 3D object bounding box (Point C) which is above the ground plane, you can draw the line directly to the y direction vanishing point (left light green line) and the same for the top-right corner point of the bounding box (Point D) (right light green line). The intersection between the light green and the dark green lines are the points where the object hits the ground (intersection between the pink and the dark green and the light green lines). If some of those points or their intersetction intersects with your ROI, the object is really intersecting with that region on the ground plane.

You will need a way to determine the 2D image points of the 3D bounding box, which can be a hard problem itself. If you know a CAD model or 3D model of your object and you have the the camera intrinsics, there are some shape fitting models available in literature, for example from the company MVTec / Halcon who also has an implementation in their software. But if you are able to determine the 3D object points in 3D according to your scene and camera then you wont even need the vanishing point thing ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for this visualization. You are telling to compute the vanishing point of the object bounding box directions. I dont have actual object coordinates, I just having the red rectangle pixel coordinates(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) in which the object is present.(It is bounding box for the that object and in that rectangle how the object is placed like their direction/position that information I don't have). In camera calibration we will get the ground plane. Can you please explain me more about how to get this green line, orange line, blue and canny lines?

Comment: getting the 3D bounding box (or farthes corner points) would be part of improving your detection algorithm. With the red bounding box in your image, you wont by far be able to estimate the right position/intersection. You see that the 2D bounding box error exceeds the needed 3D accuracy already.

Comment: orange/dark green is the projected 3D linie of the z coordinate direction (along the paper grid) which intersect in the vanishing point of that direction. The 3D lines are parallel in 3D space! The light blue lines are drawn along the object y coordinate direction (the object edge from front top corner to the front bottom corner of the object) and again exceeded to their intersection (vanishing point). The parallel edges at the back-side of the object will intersect in the same vanishing point, so you can draw the lines from the visible back top corners to that vanishing point.

Comment: the dark green lines are the ground plane edges of the the object. They start at the visible fron bottom corners and go along the vanishing line. The object ends at the intersection of the dark green and the light green line (with a lot of error because of imprecision of the drawing, lens distortion, etc.)

Comment: dark green and orange lines are parallel in 3D, so they intersect in the same vanishing point. So to construct the vanishing point I used the orange lines along the grid. You could also use the 4 visible top corner points of the object to reconstruct that vanishing point.

Comment: From object detector I only getting xmin, ymin, xmax, and ymax(that red rectangle in image(1)) for the object. I don't having this visible top corners coordinates of object. So with the help of that red rectangle only I have to find whether this red rectangle and blue ROI is intersecting or not. This is actual problem  (I am updated the question for this confusion)

Comment: Then it's not possible. I thought you wanted to improve your algorithm. Only thing you can do is choosing a camera perspective that fits perfectly for that use case.

Comment: From this red rectangle is there any way to find ground surface with tracking and camera calibration?

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: Is there any way to get this visible corner coordinate from this red rectangle region or otherwise I have to move to object segmentation?